# Error when uploading CSV file to database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm trying to upload a CSV file into an existing table in my database using PHP.

Here is my full code:

```
<?php
include("detail.php");


 $connect = mysql_connect("$host", $user, $password) or die("Couldn't connect to SQL  Server on $myServer");
 mysql_select_db("$database") or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");

 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
 }


 define('CSV_PATH','E:/4th Year/FYP/'); // specify CSV file path

  $csv_file = CSV_PATH . "Cash2011.csv"; // Name of your CSV file
 $csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
 $theData = fgets($csvfile);
 $i = 0;
 while (!feof($csvfile))
 {
   $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
   $csv_array = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
   $insert_csv = array();
   $insert_csv['cashAmount'] = $csv_array[0];
   $insert_csv['cashReceivedDate'] = $csv_array[1];
   $insert_csv['customerID'] = $csv_array[2];
   $insert_csv['invoiceNo'] = $csv_array[3];
   $insert_csv['monthNum'] = $csv_array[4];
   $insert_csv['yearNum'] = $csv_array[5];
   $query = "INSERT INTO cash2011(cashAmount,cashReceivedDate,invoiceNo,monthNum,yearNum) VALUES ('','".$insert_csv['cashAmount']."','".$insert_csv['cashReceivedDate']."','".$insert_csv['customerID']."','".$insert_csv['invoiceNo']."','".$insert_csv['monthNum']."','".$insert_csv['yearNum']."')";
   $n=mysql_query($query, $connect);
   $i++;
   }
   fclose($csvfile);
   echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
   ?>
```

These are the errors that I keep receiving:
Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\clearTables.php on line 47 (which is $insert_csv['cashAmount'] = $csv_array[0];). Undefined offset: 2 in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\clearTables.php on line 48.

Does anyone know what the problem is?
Thanks

Comment: waht does print_r($csv_array) show you?

Comment: to make it a little cleaner,  why not make your vars something like $cashAmount = $csv_array[0];   this way you can just insert $cashAmount instead of $insert_csv['cashAmount']; nothing wrong with what are doing there, just a little cleaner IMO

Comment: are you sure all the lines in your CSV file contain 6 values like cash, something, something else, etc. seems like some lines have only 1 value in them.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're doing any [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) at all here and probably have some severe [SQL injection bugs]. You're also using the deprecated `mysql_query` which should not be used in new applications because it's being removed from future versions of PHP. [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and provides a simple, reliable way of adding data to queries. A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) outlines best practices.

Answer (score 0):

i tested your code, and work very nice... 
and, when i echo the query, return:

```
    INSERT INTO cash2011(cashAmount,cashReceivedDate,invoiceNo,monthNum,yearNum) 
VALUES ('','ad4213','ad4214','ad4215','ad4216','adware','ad7777 ')
    //'','ad4213','ad4214','ad4215','ad4216','adware','ad7777 ' -> data in my example csv file
```

a few things.. 
i believe that your file doesn't exist, that is why you have those errors, try to check with this line before the  `while (!feof($file))`

```
 if(is_file($csv_file)){ //your code}
```

also, in your query, you have 5 values, and only 4 in the rows definition.
and, why you have a `,` there?

if your problem continue, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006099/wierd-bug-when-reading-from-a-csv-file-and-importing-data-into-mysql-using-php/17006256#17006256) , if you look, is a similar code of yours.

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax error in following code. So replace

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cash2011(cashAmount,cashReceivedDate,invoiceNo,monthNum,yearNum) VALUES ('','".$insert_csv['cashAmount']."','".$insert_csv['cashReceivedDate']."','".$insert_csv['customerID']."','".$insert_csv['invoiceNo']."','".$insert_csv['monthNum']."','".$insert_csv['yearNum']."')";
```

By

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cash2011(cashAmount,cashReceivedDate,invoiceNo,monthNum,yearNum) VALUES ('".$insert_csv['cashAmount']."','".$insert_csv['cashReceivedDate']."','".$insert_csv['customerID']."','".$insert_csv['invoiceNo']."','".$insert_csv['monthNum']."','".$insert_csv['yearNum']."')";
```